Библиотека python sockets не отправляет данные на сервер
Библиотека socket в python не отправляет сообщения на сервер, хотя получение сообщений от сервера работает нормально. Я пробовал подключаться несколько раз, переписывать код, но отправка данных по прежнему не работает. Вот пример кода:
import socket
import re
server_address = 'example.com'
server_port = 10331
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_address = (server_address, server_port)
print('Connecting')
sock.connect(server_address)
data = sock.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
print('received {!r}'.format(data))
login_message = f'login nickname="test" clientname="testbot"'
print('sending login message')
sock.sendall(login_message.encode('utf-8'))
while True:
    data = sock.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
    if data:
        print('received {!r}'.format(data))
    else:
        break
sock.close()


А откуда вы знаете, что отправка не работает? Если sock.sendall выполнился и не выпало исключение, значит все данные были отосланы.
